# What is the assertion method which we should use when you need to check validation for mandatory text boxes in codedUI Automation?

Tags: c#

Assume that you have mandatory text box field, and you need to apply an assertion to check whether it's blank when you click on "Save" button. I record the scenario in codedUI Recorder and generate the code as well. After that, I add an assertion IsNotNul(). It didn't work properly but it generates the report and even when you look at the summary report all the test data is passed which is wrong.

Please help me to sort out this issue. Which assertion I should use and How???

Comment: It's not clear what kind of assertion you're talking about. Assertions are usually used to catch coding errors, not for user input validation in my experience. I suspect you want to be checking against an empty string rather than null though.

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes, I need to check for empty string. How should I do it? It's for automation in codedUI.

Comment: It would probably help to add CodedUI as a tag - I've never come across it myself...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're doing Unit Testing of some sort, thus the Assertions. As @Jon stated. Use something like `Assert.AreNotEqual(yourString, String.Empty);`

You could also use something like `.IsTrue` or `.IsFalse` as long as you organize the contents of the Assertion to check whether the string is empty or not.